# Can I get SSH to use an askpass program even if it was run from a terminal?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

[`man ssh`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html) says:

```
SSH_ASKPASS
   If  ssh needs a passphrase, it will read the passphrase from the
   current terminal if it was run from a terminal.  If ssh does not
   have  a  terminal associated with it but DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS
   are set, it will execute the program  specified  by  SSH_ASKPASS
   and open an X11 window to read the passphrase.
```

I'd like SSH to use an askpass program even if it was run from a terminal.

On occasion, I have to connect to servers, where there's some delay in showing a password prompt (maybe due to network issues, maybe due to attempted reverse DNS lookups, …). I get annoyed and switch to something else, and forget about the attempted connection. (Insert joke about attention span of a goldfish.) When I finally get back to it, the prompt's timed out and even a correct password would just result in a closed connection.

Keys would be one solution, but not every system I use has my usual SSH keys. However, I usually use Ubuntu systems, and Ubuntu has an SSH askpass program installed by default.

If an askpass window popped up, however, I'd be immediately aware of it. That's a good enough compromise for me, if only I can get it to work.

Comment: Good question. From looking at the source code, it doesn't look like it. You'd have to trick it into failing to open `/dev/tty` (`LD_PRELOAD`?).

Comment: @Celada would that cause problems when starting the shell?

Comment: Probably not...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will be a bit more complicated, but combination of several pieces will make it working:

### Explanation

1. To force `ssh` to use `$SSH_ASKPASS` program, you can't allow `ssh` to see the real `tty`. It is just condition. This can be done by using `setsid` and using `-n` switch to `ssh`.

   This case would initiate connection, but you would not be able to interact with the shell, which is probably also your requirement ;) (and also breaks your local TTY).

   But you can give up the "first session". You should also add `-N` switch, which will suppress the remote command and will do **just the authentication**.

   Also the possible output "junk" can be redirected to `&> /dev/null` if you are not interested in it.
2. Set up `ControlMaster` in `ssh_config`. It is cool feature and once the connection is established, you can "fire up" sessions pretty fast. This snippet in `~/.ssh/config` should do that:

   ```
   ControlPath ~/.ssh/controlmasters/%r@%h:%p
   ControlMaster auto
   ControlPersist 5m
   ```

   You can add that into some `host` block listing your "slow candidates", or just everywhere. It is almost no overhead.

### Final line

Then you should be able to connect in this way to the host you expect it will take a while:

```
setsid ssh -nN host
# wait, insert password in the X11 prompt
ssh host
# will bring you directly to your session
```

Whole process might be simplified by `alias` or bash function doing both in one step, but it is left on readers imagination.

## Only command-line arguments

You can join both things together on command-line without `ssh_config` part:

```
setsid ssh -nNMS ~/.ssh/masters/%C host
# wait, insert password in the X11 prompt
ssh -S ~/.ssh/masters/%C host
# will bring you directly to your session
```

---

The following function should work when SSH options aren't specified:

```sh
ssh() {
    if ! command ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no "$1" true
    then
        setsid -w ssh -fnN "$1"
    fi
    command ssh "$@"
}
```

- `-f` instructs SSH to go to the background just before program execution, which is after it has got the password.
- `-w` tells `setsid` to wait for the program to end. In this case, that happens when SSH goes to the background. Combined with `ssh -f`, the manual wait between the two SSH commands can be eliminated.
- The function assumes the first argument is the hostname.
- The test is just to prevent unnecessary SSH connections.

Comment: `ControlMaster` is already setup, precisely because it's such a pain to enter passwords in such cases. It shouldn't be difficult to write a function which tests for an existing master and uses the askpass if it couldn't find one. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

With OpenSSH 8.4 you can set `$SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE` environment variable to `force`. Quoting [ssh(1)](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE) man page:

```
 SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE   Allows further control over the use of
                       an askpass program.  If this variable
                       is set to "never" then ssh will never
                       attempt to use one.  If it is set to
                       "prefer", then ssh will prefer to use
                       the askpass program instead of the TTY
                       when requesting passwords.  Finally, if
                       the variable is set to "force", then
                       the askpass program will be used for
                       all passphrase input regardless of
                       whether DISPLAY is set.
```

As OpenSSH 8.4 was released [September 27, 2020](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.4) you will need to wait a bit to have this feature available in any major Linux distribution.

Comment: Knowing that this now exists has saved me a lot of hassle. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A per SSH manual (`man ssh`):

> If `ssh` does not have a terminal associated with it but DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS are set, it will execute the program specified by SSH_ASKPASS.

Therefore you need to disassociate the terminal (e.g. by adding a pipe) and make sure `DISPLAY` isn't set (if you want to use terminal for your passphrase instead).

Simple example:

```
echo foo | SSH_ASKPASS=/my/cmd DISPLAY= ssh ...
```

The same with `ssh-add`:

```
$ echo foo | SSH_ASKPASS=/my/cmd DISPLAY= ssh-add id_rsa
ssh_askpass: exec(/my/cmd): No such file or directory
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. It does say `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal`, so it seems that the pipe is doing something. `ssh </dev/null` had the same effect. However in both cases it still asks for a password, and I can still type one in. I tried on Linux and Mac. I tried `ssh -vvv` but it doesn't say anything useful.

Comment: `SSH_ASKPASS=/foo DISPLAY= setsid ssh host` works though.